Maximum SPI devices with Arduino Mega
I am planning to connect

5 SPI based LS7366R counter ICs,
3 SPI connected stepper motor driver feedback ICs and
1 SPI connected W5500 ethernet controller

through SPI of Arduino Mega 2560.
So total of 9 devices.
Will this be ok to work with this way? Is there a way to reduce data consistency risks ?

This is a problem of bus length/resistance rather than number of nodes.

Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum. Please read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help], too. Then come back and address all comments by [edit]ing your question. -- Why are you expecting data consistency risks? What reasons do you have in mind causing these risks? -- You will need the data sheets of all devices to check the fulfillment of their requirements.

Each SPI device requires a separate CS pin. The Arduino Mega has several digital pins available, so you can assign each device its unique CS pin. Your setup should work with 9 SPI devices if you manage the CS lines properly.
